# How can I change the size or the color of my spinner checkbox?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm working on an Android Project which allow the user to select a list of item in an Alert Dialog (see the image below).

[image]

I'm using android.widget.spinner. But the checkbox aren't well visible.

I'm trying to personalize the checkbox because this kind are by default.

So is it possible to replace them by my own checkbox?

Comment: yes .. it .. is :-) you need to create your own drawables for it

Comment: yep @Blundell, I try the example given below by Avadhani. Exactly I have a checkbox which changed (checked) when I click on it. But the problem is how to integrate the layout on my project. The xml file of simple_spinner_item is a textview with a specific style. I can't replace it with my new xml file

Comment: you'll now have to use your own custom spinner item and replace it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create yourself a drawable:

my_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_checkbox_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_checkbox_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_checkbox_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_checkbox_default"/> <!-- pressed -->

</selector>
```

this goes in `/drawable/`

You then have to create the four drawables, these will be png files and you will want to create one for each size of screen i.e. `/drawable-mdpi` etc

You can grab these from the Android source and just modify them if it is easier.
(as an example look here http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/ and search for checkbox)

Then just use this as your checkbox for your row item layout

```
<CheckBox
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox"
/>
```

---

simple_spinner_item just looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

All you have to do is create your own layout file called:

my_simple_spinner item.xml put it in `drawable` and add your custom checkbox:

```
<LinearLayout />
  <TextView />
  <CheckBox android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then set this as the layout for each row and handle the checkbox selection yourself... that's the price of customisation.

Comment: Thanks @Blundell for your answer. Since you post it, I work on it but nothing. In "my_simple_spinner_item", I added **android:height and width**. I've got an Inflate error (Binary xml class Eroor Inflating class Checkbox)

Comment: Sorry @Blundell I don't understand your last comment!!

Comment: @zim capital B not lowercase b

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way in your layout file.

`main.xml`

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:background="@color/border" <--- android built-in style. You can define your own whichever you like. Check for it.
> android:orientation="horizontal" >
> <CheckBox
>     android:id="@+id/check"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/Textname"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
>     android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
>     android:textSize="14dp"
>     android:textStyle="bold" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will help you, but I have done custom spinners in one of my projects where I have to set a custom background and font size. I have code like below.

You can try it out. Inside `string.xml` write:

```
   <string-array name="spinner_array_environtment">
        <item>Test</item>
        <item>Production</item>
    </string-array>
```

Inside your MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner spinner_environment;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                spinner_environment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerview);
adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,              R.array.spinner_array_environtment,R.layout.spinner_phone);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spinner_environment.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Inside spinner_phone.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="#4C4646" />
```

Try this out. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the background of the `checkbox` right? Then do as below:

```
 checkBox.setButtonDrawable(<YourClass>.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.checkradio));   // where check radio is an xml file as shown below:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_option" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_option" android:state_checked="true"/>
```

where `unselected_option` is an image for displaying when `checkbox` is not checked and `selected_option` is an image for displaying `checkbox` background when option is checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not trying to change the background of the checkbox. Sometimes the user don't know he has to select an item or more. So what I'm trying to do is to make the checkbox more focusable without changing the background.

Comment: ok @zim then place "@color/white" instead of "@drawable/unselected_option" for displaying initially the checkbox as bright

Comment: No @Avadhani. Did you have another one??

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is to create a custom spinner ....

you have to make a xml file which contains textview and checkbox (as per your required size)

after that you have to inflate your new xml onto spinner..

code to inflate custom view :  this is just an example

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
            label.setText(strings[position]);

            TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            sub.setText(subs[position]);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

            return row;
            }
        }
```